# Can I rely on TSC increment frequency for VM detection?

Tags: operating-system, virtualization

I need to detect whether my code runs on VM knowing that some of my users will try to fake it, pretending that it runs on a real machine while it doesn't. AFAIK it's not a very good idea to rely on vendor or device name since it can be overridden by changing VM settings or replacing BIOS firmware. The question is, can I rely on TSC frequency?

Answer (score 3):

> The question is, can I rely on TSC frequency?

Short answer: No (maybe)

For using the TSC frequency in a literal way (like "This CPU's TSC frequency is supposed to be 2345 MHz but TSC frequency was measured as 1234 MHz"); typically (for software that other people install on unknown computers) there's no way to know what the CPU's TSC frequency is supposed to be; given that the hyper-visor can tell you anything it feels like via. `cpuid` (and there's no way to determine what the TSC frequency is supposed to be without relying `cpuid` in some way).

For a simple hyper-visor you may be able to use the TSC to detect that something caused a "trap to hyper-visor" (because it takes much longer than it would've on bare metal).

However, a more sophisticated hyper-visor can hide its time consumption by virtualizing the TSC. This can include a kind of "rubber banding" technique - e.g. tell the guest that the "virtual TSC frequency" is a little slower than the real TSC frequency, and then introduce brief pauses if/when the "virtual TSC" gets too far ahead. Alternatively, the hyper-visor could just tell the guest that "virtual TSC frequency" is the same as the real TSC's frequency, hide the extra time consumption of "trap to hyper-visor" by reducing a "TSC offset", and then smoothing out the TSC offset over time so that the guest can't tell where the time went (and can't know if the time wasn't consumed by something else, like System Management Mode or slightly slower RAM or ..).

Mostly; what you end up with is a kind of race - as you find new ways to detect VMs, the VM developers find new ways to improve their virtualization and prevent detection.

Comment: But VMs don't fake wall clock time, so I could compare TSC read timings against the wall clock time? Say to compare diff between idle period increment in TSC value with increment taken while intensive TSC-reading using wall clock time.

Comment: @ababo: Some VMs also fake wall clock time (and some can be set to "deterministic timing, wall clock time is completely fake, real wall clock time is irrelevant") . If wall clock time isn't fake but TSC is; then TSC can tell you anything it likes for "time spent idle" and anything it likes for "time spent doing intensive TSC-reading", and make sure both cases conform to a plausible reality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare multiple time sources together. If you can, you should compare multiple cores together.

The easiest workaround to TSC-based detection is to do the rubberbanding that Brendan mentioned. But it's harder to cheat TSC when more than one core is involved. The TSC offset/multiplier is per-core. Each VMEXIT will cause the TSCs to skew if the VMM is trying to hide itself.

Now, the VMM could try to kick out the other vCPUs when any individual core exits so that they can synchronize TSCs, but that is incredibly expensive (and probably has other detectable issues, since it's hard to synchronize the vCPUs reentering).

In summary, you want at least two cores:

1. One core should set an atomic variable, call RDTSC, then call a bunch of instructions with mandatory VMEXITs, (e.g. CPUID), call RDTSC, and then unset the atomic variable.
2. Another core should monitor that atomic variable, then call rdtsc, then monitor it again, and finally call rdtsc once it gets unset.

This will take some calibration. Timing can be pretty finicky with things like this.
Additionally, you can use a loop incrementing a variable to act as a proxy for rdtsc, but the calibration for this can be even more finicky (but worthwhile, since TSC can universally lie, including in the second core mentioned above).